# Using ffmpeg-python to combine cv2 video streaming and pyaudio audio streaming

Tags: ffmpeg, python, video-streaming, audio-streaming

I want to use my camera and microphone to get living video and audio streaming and use ffmpeg to combine them.So I write it by python.there is my code.

```python
import os,pyaudio,cv2,ffmpeg 
p=pyaudio.PyAudio() 
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
aud = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=2, rate=44100, input=True, frames_per_buffer=1024) 
vidstream = vid.read()[1] 
audstream = aud.read(1024) 
ffmpeg.concat(vidstream, audstream, v=1, a=1).output('finished_video.mp4').run()
```

and it is error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/home/pi/Desktop/ffmpegtest.py", line 13, in ffmpeg.concat(vidstream, audstream, v=1, a=1).output('finished_video.mp4').run() 
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ffmpeg/_filters.py", line 399, in concat return FilterNode(streams, concat.name, kwargs=kwargs, max_inputs=None).stream() 
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ffmpeg/nodes.py", line 266, in init super(FilterNode, self).init( File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ffmpeg/nodes.py", line 202, in init self.__check_input_types(stream_map, incoming_stream_types) 
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ffmpeg/nodes.py", line 172, in __check_input_types 
raise TypeError( 
TypeError: Expected incoming stream(s) to be of one of the following types: ffmpeg.nodes.FilterableStream; got <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I can understand it very well,Is this mean I should convert the type of video and audio? And what should I do?

Comment: Since you are asking in Super User site, try not use any programming. I recommend you to delete your two questions, do some research and ask a question about using FFmpeg command line. Search in Google: *ffmpeg grab webcam* and *ffmpeg record webcam* or  *ffmpeg record webcam video and audio*.... If you must use Python, post a question in Stack Overflow (but do some research first).

Comment: Is there any reason you use the ffmpeg python wrapper?

Comment: because I want to translate video and audio streaming from my raspberry to computer,and I use python socket to translate data,so I just want to use ffmpeg-python to implement it,but I think use command line by python os is okey?

Comment: but the trouble is I just can found the command line to combine two exist file or streaming from camera and mirocphone,but I cannot found a command to marge two data streaming which I get in PC